# Rails 4 - Creating bills about products I have listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-relations

I have a model `Product` about all the products I offer in my shop This is basically just `name:string` and `price:decimal`.

On the other side I have a model `Bill` where I list an amount of `Products` sold. I thought of making a relation M:N between Bills and Products, that way a `Bill` could sell many products and a `Product` could be sold in different Bills.

**But the following problem happens:** What if I change after a couple years the price of a Product? If I try to check up on Bills that have been issued in the past, I will get the wrong amounts.

What would be the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Why not just save Product's current price on a Bill as well? In a JSON for example, then you could have multiple Product's on a Bill with their current price independent of what the price of the Product is in a couple of years. Or add a 3rd relation something like Transaction where you have Product, Price it was bought for and a Bill id. Then Bill would have multiple Transactions and it would not matter if Product's price was changed.

Comment: With the 3rd relation, no. You can also add Product amount to Transaction. Then you would just query `Transaction.where("product_id = yourid and created_at between X and Y").sum(:productamount)` etc. Should be quite easy. I think if you plan to change Product and want to keep record of what changed on a Bill + have other data like amount and price, you will need to use 3rd relation, otherwise it will be too messy and complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add 3rd relation to this one, to not make it complicated as i posted in Comment.

For example, let's call it `Transaction`

- Product has_many Transactions
- Bill has_many Transactions
- Transaction has_one Bill, Product

Transaction would have something like `product_id:integer, bill_id:integer, product_amount:integer, product_price:decimal, transaction_amount:decimal`

- `product_amount` - That would be X of units of Product bought with this Transaction, let's say i bought 10 Apples so `Transaction` object would have `product_amount` equals to 10
- `product_price` - Current price of the product at that time, with same example Price of Apple product at the time of Purchase
- `transaction_amount` - Total amount of Transaction, let's say 10xPrice of Apple

That way you would be able to track how much amounts of Product were bought at Y time, what was the product price at that time and how much was total sum.

Now when you wanted to know how much units of X Product you sold in Y month you would `Transaction.where("product_id = ? and created_at between Y and Y", x.id).sum(:product_amount)`

Comment: What is the difference between product_amount, product_price and transaction_amount?

Comment: @Dbugger `product_amount` - That would be X of units of Product bought with this Transaction, let's say i bought 10 Apples so Transaction object would have `product_amount` equals to 10. `product_price` - Current price of the product at that time, with same example Price of Apple product at the time of Purchase. `transaction_amount` - Total amount of Transaction, let's say 10xPrice of Apple

Comment: In that case: a) `transaction_amount` is a unnecessary field, since it can be calculated from the other 2 fields, no? b) If a product was to be altered (like the name description) or even deleted, that would break the Transactions (and therefore the Bills) where they appear, no?

Comment: @Dbugger - Yes, `transaction_amount` is not really necessary to have but a nice attribute for an object such as Transaction in a matter of how most finance apps work. If a Product would be altered, then name of Product would be changed indeed if you called it from `Transaction.first.product` relation, but that's how it should work. It would also break calling Product from Transaction if you deleted Product indeed. In this case you can always add more attributes to Transaction to make them permanent incase Product get's deleted like `product_desc:string, product_name:desc` etc.